# Stackoverflow like Urls with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, slug

Most tutorials about prettifying Urls in Rails explain how to get Urls like `www.example.org/resource/3-some-sluggish-slug`, which is very easy by using the to_param method.

What I want is to prettify Urls in a Rails 3 app like Stackoverflow does (`www.example.org/resource/3/some-sluggish-slug`). The `some-sluggish-slug` could be any string there, it is just for having a nicer Url and is simply ignored by all logic (like in Stackoverflow). Is there an easy way to do that, too? Or do I have to rewrite the Url somehow before it gets to the routes file or in the routes file itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the tutorials, but instead of having a hyphen after the ID, have a `/`. You will need to write a route to cope with this.

```
  match 'resource/:id', :to => 'resources#show', :id => /\d+\/[a-z0-9\-]+/, :as => 'public_post'
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to define your own routes; see [the Rails guide section 3](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) and onwards.